# Private Params not found on form submission (sunspot, solr)

Tags: ruby, solr, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, strong-parameters

Basic searching using Sunspot & Solr...just searching one attribute (title) of one model (Collection)

On form submission i get the error

```
param not found: collection
```

And it points back to this private method in the collections_controller

```
def collection_params
  params.require(:collection).permit(:title, :cover_photo)
end
```

any ideas on why??

**EDIT:**

Index method on the collections_controller

```
def index
  @search = Collection.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end
  @collection = @search.results
end
```

Collection model:

```
searchable do
  text :title
end
```

And my form tag

```
<%= form_tag collections_path :method => :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems like you're mixing 2 things here.  Your `collection_params` isn't referenced in that controller method, so I'm not sure how it would give you that error.  I'm also not sure strong parameters would really be all that useful in a search method to begin with.

Comment: Please post the output from the terminal window running the web server (rails s) when you make the  request and get the error?